# Get Correct Application Process

Tags: c#, process, task

How can I get an application's process if more than one instance is open.

```
var processList= Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess");
```

Example:-

2 chrome browsers are open. In the list of processes in the tast mgr, I have 2 chrome processes.
I run an application that starts chrome using some Apis "not through Process.Start("")". Now I have 3 in the Task Mgr porcesses

How can I get the process that my application started, and not the other 2 that were already open ? how can I distinguish between the 3 processes that I will get from the statement above

I tried sorting them based on the **TotalProcessorTime** property, and get the one with the shortest time, but what if I decided to a open another chrome after that, I will get the wrong process.

Comment: What do you mean correct process? So you mean if a process has the same name

Comment: Yes if I have 3 porcesses, 2 that have been started earlier. Then I started the new process, and I want to get the one I started. All of them have the same name, its the same application

Comment: When you start the process in your program, you should also have a [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) object associated with this process. (If not, use one of the _static_ [Process.Start(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads, which return a _Process_object). This _Process_ object will give you the process id and other information about the process you started...

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on the information you have given if it is always the most recent Process then you could try the following

```
MostRecentlyStartedProcess(Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess"));



public Process MostRecentlyStartedProcess(Process[] procceses)
{
  Process result = null;
  foreach (Process process in procceses)
  {
    if (result == null)
    {
      result = process;
    }
    else
    {
      if (process.StartTime < result.StartTime)
      {
        result = process;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: your answer will get the current newest process, but what if the user were to start a new process (double clicking chrome) after I already started the program. It would get the wrong process, this is where my issue is